# elementary OS lock screen configuration

Tags: release-loki, session

I would like to set the elementary OS lock screen back.

I made a miss installation of unity and when a came back by uninstalling it I found the regular login screen again:
(Regular elementary OS login screen (1))

[image: elementary os login screen]

But when I lock my session I have a different screen layout :
(Different lock screen (2))

[image]

I think that this has to do with "gnome-screensaver" that is now active and wasn't before.
I tried uninstalling the screen-saver, but that makes me unable to unlock the session when locked. The login windows disappears but no other login possibility is then available. I have to shut down and reboot to login again.

Has anyone an idea how to make the regular elementary login screen (1) coming up when locking the session ?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt purge lightdm
sudo apt autoremove lightdm
sudo apt install lightdm
```

Comment: This is not working to remove the lock-screen. I think lightdm is the locker I actually have. I would like to go back to the elementary locker (same as login screen). I tried to remove lightdm, but that let's me with nothing.

Comment: i did that and now i cant lock the screen , any solutions ?

Comment: @iago you probably need to reinstall `light-locker`

Answer (score 0):

if you run `light-locker` at one terminal lock will work ...
but running `light-locker-settings` give me this error , still investigating
light-locker-settings

```
(light-locker-settings.py:10794): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:06:34.602: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.
/usr/share/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings.py:29: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib, Gio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings.py", line 702, in <module>
    main = LightLockerSettings()
  File "/usr/share/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.init_settings()
  File "/usr/share/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings.py", line 440, in init_settings
    settings = self.gsettings_get_settings()
  File "/usr/share/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings.py", line 276, in gsettings_get_settings
    settings['light-locker-enabled'] = self.get_light_locker_enabled()
  File "/usr/share/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings.py", line 499, in get_light_locker_enabled
    keyfile = self.get_light_locker_autostart()
  File "/usr/share/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings.py", line 384, in get_light_locker_autostart
    self.get_autostart('light-locker.desktop', defaults)
  File "/usr/share/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings.py", line 358, in get_autostart
    GLib.KeyFileFlags.KEEP_TRANSLATIONS)
GLib.Error: g-key-file-error-quark: Valid key file could not be found in search dirs (2)
```